# Scrapy Python xpath for <mark>

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to extract with scrapy some information contained on  tags with .xpath or .css on Scrapy.

But I want to put some condition and I have no idea how to that.
For example, let's see this HTML code of the webpage that I want to scrap.

```
<div data-tabs-content="" class="estateTabs-panels">
  <div id="detail" data-tabs-pane="" class="estateTabs-panel active">
   <ul class="dotted-list dotted-list--ocom">
    <li><mark>Nombre de pièce(s)
     </mark> <mark>3</mark>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li><mark>Nombre de chambre(s)</mark>
    <mark>2</mark>
    </li>                              
    <li> 
    <mark>Surface</mark>
    <li><mark>70.68m²</mark>
    </li>
```

My problem is for each page of the website, values inside `<mark>` tag are different and I want to extract, for example,  for `<mark>2</mark>` the value 2 if the previous mark tag contains "Nombre de chambre(s)".

For example, I wanted to do something like this:

```
if elt.css(".XXXX").extract_first() == ' Nombre de chambre(s) ':
       item['value'] = elt.css(".XXXX").extract_first()
```

and the result must be 2

For the moment I can just scrap with this way:

```
item['value'] = info.css('.estateTabs-panel ::text').extract()[4]
```

but I don't want to use `[int]` because for each page the values are different.

Is it possible with mark tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create condition directly in your xpath query :

```
import scrapy

html = '<div data-tabs-content="" class="estateTabs-panels"> ' \
       '<div id="detail" data-tabs-pane="" class="estateTabs-panel active">' \
       '<ul class="dotted-list dotted-list--ocom">' \
       ' <li><mark>Nombre de pièce(s)' \
       '</mark> <mark>3</mark>' \
       '</li>' \
       '<li>' \
       '<li><mark>Nombre de chambre(s)</mark>' \
       '<mark>2</mark>' \
       '</li>' \
       '<li>' \
       '<mark>Surface</mark>' \
       '<li><mark>70.68m²</mark>' \
       '</li></ul></div></div>'

response = scrapy.Selector(text=html, type="html")

text = response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Nombre de chambre(s)')]/following-sibling::mark/text()")

print(text.get())
```

Return :

```
2
```

The xpath query is looking for an element containing "Nombre de chambre(s)". If it find it, it will get the following "mark" element. From this element, the text will be taken.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do the same using `selector` then this is what you can try as well:

```
import scrapy

htmldoc="""
<div data-tabs-content="" class="estateTabs-panels">
  <div id="detail" data-tabs-pane="" class="estateTabs-panel active">
   <ul class="dotted-list dotted-list--ocom">
    <li><mark>Nombre de pièce(s)
     </mark> <mark>3</mark>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li><mark>Nombre de chambre(s)</mark>
    <mark>2</mark>
    </li>                              
    <li> 
    <mark>Surface</mark>
    <li><mark>70.68m²</mark>
    </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
"""
res = scrapy.Selector(text=htmldoc)
text = res.css("mark:contains('Nombre de chambre') + mark::text").extract_first()
print(text)
```

Output:

```
2
```